# Iterate through list and assign a value to the variable in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, variables, differential-equations

So i'm currently working on code, which solves simple differentials. For now my code looks something like that:

```
deff diff():
coeffs = []
#checking a rank of a function
lvl = int(raw_input("Tell me a rank of your function: "))
if lvl == 0:
    print "\nIf the rank is 0, a differential of a function will always be 0"
#Asking user to write coefficients (like 4x^2 - he writes 4)
for i in range(0, lvl):
    coeff = int(raw_input("Tell me a coefficient: "))
    coeffs.append(coeff)
#Printing all coefficients
print "\nSo your coefficients are: "
for item in coeffs:
    print item
```

And so what I want to do next? I have every coefficient in my coeffs[] list. So now I want to take every single one from there and assign it to a different variable, just to make use of it. And how can I do it? I suppose I will have to use loop, but I tried to do so for hours - nothing helped me. Sooo, how can I do this? It would be like : `a=coeff[0], b = coeff[1], ..., x = coeff[lvl]` .

Comment: your never making lvl an int

Comment: No, you really do *not* want to assign them to separate variables. They are in the list. Access them directly from there.

Comment: Okay, I will make it an int, my bad. But it's not a problem. I can acces them directly from a list, but, how can I tell the program to use only given coeffs, count themm, or smth

Comment: @Frynio you can index the coeffs you can do anything that you want to do with a variable using list just be specify of your problem

Comment: `coeffs[0]+coeffs[1]`? or `sum(coeffs)`?

Comment: FYI: numpy as polyfit, polyval and polyder routines to fit, evaluate and take the derivative of simple polynomials - in case you want a reference implementation to test against.

Comment: @Frynio If you want to count them just use `len(foeffs)`, how could you count them (better) if they were put in separate variables?

Comment: Downvote - I think you should clarify why you think you want to do that: What do you hope to achieve by doing this? Why can't you access them directly in the list? And so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY want to assign a list to variables you could do so by accessing the `globals()` dict. For example:

```
for j in len(coeffs):
     globals()["elm{0}".format(j)] = coeffs[j]
```

Then you'll have your coefficients in the global variables `elm0`, `elm1` and so on.

Please note that this is most probably not what you really want (but only what you asked for).

Comment: It answers the question, but please explicetly say that it is **BAD**, before being downvoted ...

Comment: He asked for a bad thing and he got it, I don't see the point in downvoting the answer in that case. However I added a note about it.

Comment: Some downvote when they see bad pratices in an answer without a notice. I just wanted to warn you for that. But I do prefere your edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

Just access the coefficients directly from the list via their indices.

If you are wanting to use the values in a different context that entails making changes to the values but you want to keep the original list unchanged then copy the list to a new list,

```
import copy

mutableCoeffs = copy.copy(coeffs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need new variables.

You already have all you need to compute the coefficients for the derivative function.

```
print "Coefficients for the derivative:"
l = len(coeffs) -1
for item in coeffs[:-1]:
    print l * item
    l -=1
```

Or if you want to put them in a new list :

```
deriv_coeffs = []
l = len(coeffs) -1
for item in coeffs[:-1]:
    deriv_coeffs.append(l * item)
    l -=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess from there you want to differenciate no? So you just assign the cofficient times it rank to the index-1?

```
deff diff():

    coeffs = []
    #checking a rank of a function
    lvl = int(raw_input("Tell me a rank of your function: "))
    if lvl == 0:
        print "\nIf the rank is 0, a differential of a function will always be 0"
    #Asking user to write coefficients (like 4x^2 - he writes 4)
    for i in range(0, lvl):
        coeff = int(raw_input("Tell me a coefficient: "))
        coeffs.append(coeff)
    #Printing all coefficients
    print "\nSo your coefficients are: "
    for item in coeffs:
        print item  
    answer_coeff = [0]*(lvl-1)
    for i in range(0,lvl-1):
        answer_coeff[i] = coeff[i+1]*(i+1)
    print "The derivative is:"
    string_answer = "%d" % answer_coeff[0]
    for i in range(1,lvl-1):
        string_answer = string_answer + (" + %d * X^%d" % (answer_coeff[i], i))
    print string_answer
```